# Can't share Internet connection from MacBook to iPhone

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, bluetooth

I have my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.4) connected via WiFi. 
iPhone 5s 8.4 is connected via bluetooth to the MBP. But I can't navigate on the Internet from my phone. 
Here's the setup:

[image: internet sharing tab]

[image: Network tab]

Can someone help me to navigate the Internet from the iPhone using the MacBook's connection?

Comment: You can’t easily reshare WiFi over USB. Can your Mac connect over Ethernet - that’s trivial to re-share with WiFi internet sharing - almost one click in preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking seems unclear, but I think you are asking if you can share internet connectivity from your computer to your iPhone (or other iOS devices) via Bluetooth.

In this case the answer is no this is not possible, however you can share via Wi-Fi.

You can share (tether) your iPhone, or Cellular iPad's data connections to your computer via Bluetooth, USB or Wi-Fi but not the reverse.

[This article on Apple.com explains the later option](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204023)

Comment: You can share an Ethernet Internet connection on a Mac via Wi-Fi to any iOS device

Comment: what are you saying? sure you can share your internet connection. I want to share the connection of my computer (getting internet from wifi) to my iphone (via bluetooth).

Comment: Sorry @JaimeSantaCruz you are correct, but not bluetooth, that answer wasn't great, I've modified it.

Comment: @Danny182 If I am wrong then I take it back, but I am pretty sure you can't share your internet from your computer via bluetooth to the phone... Sure the other way is fine, but not from the computer via bluetooth to the phone.

Comment: @unknowndomain: You are implying that the checkbox for Bluetooth sharing has never done anything and Apple has not bothered to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To share the WIFI internet connection on one MacBook to another MacBook (iOS devices will be similar) via bluetooth:

**On laptop WITH WIFI internet connectivity:**

1. Preferences >> Sharing >> Internet Sharing

   - Select: "Internet Sharing"
   - Select: "Share your connection from WIFI"
   - Check: "To computers using Bluetooth PAN"
   - De-select Bluetooth Sharing (I am uncertain if this is necessary)
   - Check: Internet Sharing (and accept the dialog that opens)
2. Preferences >> Network >> WIFI

   - Click: "Advanced..."
   - Click: "TCP/IP"
   - Screenshot the IPv4 address, subnet mask and router (CMD+SHIFT+4, drag selection to capture)
   - Click: "DNS"
   - Screenshot the DNS Server(s) and Search Domain(s)
3. Preferences >> Network >> Bluetooth PAN

   - Click: "Advanced"
   - Select: "Configure IPv4 manually"
   - Input: IPv4 address, subnet mask and router per the screenshot taken above
   - Select: "Configure IPv6 Automatically"
   - Click: DNS tab
   - Input: DNS Servers and Search Domains per screenshot taken above
   - Click: OK

**On laptop WITHOUT WIFI internet connectivity:**

1. Turn WIFI off
2. Pair bluetooth with the other laptop
3. Preferences >> Network >> Bluetooth PAN

   - Select: "Device "
   - Click: Connect
   - Click: "Advanced..."
   - Select: Configure IPv4 Using DHCP
   - Select: Configure IPv6 Automatically
   - Click: DNS tab
   - Enter: DNS Servers: PAN network IP of the other laptop (probably 192.168.2.1)
   - Enter: Search domains copied from the screenshot taken on other laptop (unsure if this is necessary)
   - Click: OK

That should work. Complicated I know.